# Python: How to select form from URL response without 'name' tag

Tags: python-3.x

I try to select a form from a URL response with Python. This is the form and there is only on form available in the response.

```
<form id="login_form" data-redirect='{"type":"refresh","link":"\/"}'>
    <div class="unlogged-input-container">
        <input class="unlogged-input" type="email" id="login_mail" data-check="email" required value="" />
        <label class="unlogged-label" for="login_mail">E-Mail-Adress</label>
    </div>
    <div class="unlogged-input-container">
        <input class="unlogged-input unlogged-input-pwd" type="password" id="login_password" required />
        <label class="unlogged-label" for="login_password">Password</label>
    </div>
    <div class="recaptcha-wrapper">
        <div class="recaptcha-container">
            <div id="recaptcha_enterprise_container"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="login_form_submit" class="auth-cta gap-m-top" type="submit">
        <span class="unlogged-btn-label">Logon</span>
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" id="login_method" name="login_method" value="email">
</form>
```

With

```
print(br.select_form(nr=0))
```

it returns

```
None
```

But

```
print([f.attrs['id'] for f in br.forms()])
```

returns

```
['login_form']
```

and

```
for x in br.forms(): print(x)
```

returns

```
<GET https://www.<target_domain>/en/login application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  <TextControl(<None>=)>
  <PasswordControl(<None>=)>
  <SubmitButtonControl(<None>=) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(login_method=email) (readonly)>>
```

This is the sample code for it:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_gzip(False)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.addheaders = [
    ('User-Agent','Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'),
    ('Accept-Encoding', 'deflate,br'),
    ('Content-Type',    'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'),
    ('Cache-Control',   'no-cache'),
    ('Connection',      'keep-alive')
]
url  = 'https://<target_domain>/en/login'
br.open(url)
print([f.attrs['id'] for f in br.forms()])
print(br.select_form(nr=0))
for x in br.forms():
    print(x)
```

But how to select this form?